# Is that OK to use Klevu with ElasticSearch in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

We are using Klevu on our site. Here is their site https://www.headcovers.com/

The search autocomplete runs really fast. See here - https://prnt.sc/qpe7w6 but it's really slow with the Ajax filtering in the category page. See here - https://prnt.sc/qpe8qn

We tested and saw that the filtering process is using MySQL to search which is why it's slow and it causes MySQL to be down sometimes. Does anyone have any suggestions to improve this?

As far as I know, if we use ElasticSearch, everything will be directed to the ElasticSearch server and the search will be very fast so we won't have ever need to worry about MySQL being down. Based on the release note here https://marketplace.magento.com/klevu-module-search.html I think we can use Klevu and ElasticSearch together. Can anyone here confirm that this is the next step for us?

Any help here is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: it is not a good idea to use Klevu with ElasticSearch in Magento 2

Comment: Hi Amit. I am one of the Magento experts at Klevu. May I know what issue did you face? I am more than happy to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Tejas one of the Magento experts from Klevu. The latest version of Klevu i.e. 2.2.18 is fully compatible with ElasticSearch.
Please contact us at support@klevu.com if you have any questions further or you face any issue. we would be happy to help you further

Comment: Thank you. We have it resolved now

Comment: Thanks Toan for the updates

Comment: Hey @TejasVyas, Its not working with Elasticsearch, when we are using custom sorting(Relevance) of Klevu, and when we do filter products on PLP its shows no matching product found. And elasticsearch error says that there is no index on which it can sort as Relevance(attr code: personalised) is not a product attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Klevo Search in Magento 2.3 setup.
By default, Klevo provides a search on Products, Categories & CMS Pages.
I want to add custom indexes like Customer Data i.e. search on the basis of the customer data. How this can be achieved?
Please guide.

Rashi